# Is there anything like real time clock listener in blackberry 10?

Tags: listener, blackberry-10

There used to be a real time clock listener in previous versions of blackberry(When the coding was in java). Now I was searching the internet but couldn't find anything like a real time clock listener in blackberry 10.Can any Blackberry developer please help me?

Answer (score 2):

There are of course timers. But the real time clock listener in 'legacy' OS versions allowed an application that was idle in the background to have a thread execute without having a visible UI. This is not currently possible under BB10, however the so called headless application API will be showcased at BBJam 2013, next week. Developer access to the API should follow.